# Windows-Geolocator returns chached positions after about 15 minutes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, geolocation

I use the PositionChanged-Event from the Windows-Geolocator to display the users current location on a map. Everything works fine, but after about 15 minutes, the geolocator only returns positions that are quite old (30 seconds to one minute):

Here is a snippet from my logfile:

> **2021-04-06 18:07:23,787** INFO
> [127:WindowsGnssPositionProvider:LocatorOnPositionChanged()] ->
> LocatorOnPositionChanged vom Geolocator: Long: xxxx, Lat:
> xxxx, Accuracy: 4, Timestamp: **06.04.2021 18:06:22** +02:00,
> Source: Satellite

The distance becomes greater, the more time passes.

This is my geolocator instantiation:

```
geolocator = new Geolocator()
{
    DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High,
    ReportInterval = 1000
};
geolocator.PositionChanged += Geolocator_PositionChanged;
```

Is there a way to solve this problem or to clear the cache from the geolocator?

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but I wanted to at least add that the problem was with my own implementation. I had created too many instances of GeoCoordinateWatcher.

I think this post will not be of any help to anyone looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your Posistion changed event with a timer.
I dont know this lib but i could imagine that you this event is fired so frequently that you cant keep up but rather cash all the events and thus delay the process:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
t.Start();
t.Elapsed += Geolocator_PositionChanged;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But this is not my problem. I get positions every second, but if you look at the "Timestamp" - Property from the position (The system time at which the location was determined) you can see, that the geolocator returns old positions on every new PositionChanged-Event

Comment: did you mabye stop changeing the location? or is your location change below the threshold you defined?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I wrote the wrong property in my sample. ReportInterval = 1000 and not MovementThreshold. In my real code I wrote ReportInterval

Comment: at this point, never having used this lib, I can't help anymore...good luck! :)
You could create a new geolocater every secund and dispose the old one  :D